# JW-Player will hide when open modal box(Light Box) in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, lightbox, jwplayer

I have a problem with `jw-player`using with modal box in `Joomla`. I have one video and also have one link for submitting the comment for that video and that link will open the lightbox. What I have done so far Embedded the video on the page and put a link with Modal box(Inbuilt method of Joomla). So when I play the video it is working fine and When I click on to the comment link popup modal box open and video which is playing is hide and when I close the modal box the video will resume from the current status which is fine but I want to know why is this happening. If someone have any suggestion for that what I am doing wrong please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: Flash can be problematic in that it sometimes “shines through” other HTML elements even if it is below them on the z-axis. Therefor it is a common mechanism to _hide_ flash elements when other elements are dynamically displayed in front of them to prevent that from happening – so most likely your lightbox script does exactly that when displaying your modal.

Comment: The closing of the modal doesn't therefore seems to be destroying the video (so to speak). There might be an option to do this in the plugin.

Comment: @CBroe any solution for it?

Comment: Do you have an example link to where you are trying to run this?